# Wireless Blind Motor Control

Tags: google-home

I have a Smart Switch (Sonoff Dual WiFi Wireless Smart Switch), and I control it through a Google Home. It works as a contact, like if it was a switch:

[image: image of Wi-Fi switch (switch wi-fi module switch)]

I want to control an electric blind, that has this connections:

[image: electric blind with phase up/down and neutral]

The neutral is always connected, and, if you power up "Phase Up" the blind goes up, and if you power up "Phase Down", it goes down.

The endstop is located internally of the blind motor.

I have another switch, for manual control, with 2 buttons, up and down, and when you click one, the other disconnects automatically, so you can't press both at the same time.

Any ideas of how to join the 2 circuits, without being able to power up the 2 Phases of the Motor, and being able to control anytime, from the manual switch, or the wireless switch.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found this solution...

[image: plan of possible solution with switches]

Please, if any of you can check it.

Comment: The only problem is that there are about 11 220v relays... A bit expensive...